# LineTo() draw line in wrong place

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi

I want to add a line to my text in notepad when printing a pdf, for these purpose I hook [Enddoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-enddoc) function and use GDI`LineTo()`. but when I print my text, the `LineTo()`creates new page at the end of pdf and draws Line in it. does any body knows how can I draw line in all pdf pages without create new page ?
here is my code:

```
int  StopPrint::hookFunction(HDC hdc, const DOCINFOW *lpdi)
{
    HPEN hPen1 = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 1, BLACK_PEN);
    HGDIOBJ l = hPen1;
    HPEN holdPen = (HPEN)SelectObject(hdc, l);    
    SelectObject(hdc, hPen1);
    MoveToEx(hdc, 500, 500, NULL);
    LineTo(hdc, 2000, 2000);    
     
    return getOriginalFunction()(hdc, lpdi);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've no idea if this will work or quite what you're up to, but I think you need to 'hook' `EndPage` rather than `EndDoc`.  Also, your hook function is broken in various ways so try this:

```
int StopPrint::EndPageHook(HDC hdc)
{
    HPEN holdPen = (HPEN) SelectObject(hdc, GetStockObject (BLACK_PEN));
    POINT old_pos;
    MoveToEx(hdc, 500, 500, &old_pos);
    LineTo(hdc, 2000, 2000);    
    MoveToEx(hdc, old_pos.x, old_pos,y, NULL);
    SelectObject(hdc, holdPen);
    
    return getOriginalEndPage()(hdc);
}
```

Pretty weird line BTW, that looks wrong to me.  Might want to start from (something derived from) the current position, see what you get.

Comment: i want to add watermark before print and this is a test line...

Comment: Fair enough.  Did it work? (Also, I added the `winapi` tag.)

Comment: @MohammadrezaHojatoleslami Cool.  Don't forget to clean up your GDI resources in your hook proc!